# WCF Test Client error: Failed to Invoke the service

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-client

I'm getting an error when trying to use the WCF Test Client with my WCF service. Here is the service code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmployeeService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "GetEmployee")]
    [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        UriTemplate = "/Employees/{employeeNumber}")]
    Employee GetEmployee(string employeeNumber);
}

public Employee GetEmployee(string employeeNumber)
{
    var employeeNumberValue = Convert.ToInt32(employeeNumber);
    var employee = DataProvider.GetEmployee(employeeNumberValue);
    return employee;
}

<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Employees.Services.EmployeeService"
                 behaviorConfiguration="metaBehavior">
            <endpoint address=""
                      behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="Employees.Services.IEmployeeService">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex"
                      binding="mexHttpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webHttp">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="metaBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am able to connect to the service using the WCF Test Client, but when I try to invoke GetEmployee(employeeNumber) I get the following error:

*Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.*

I was able to successfully call this service by sending a request from the browser.

Any idea why I can't use the WCF Test Client?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please ignore my earlier answer. I don't think the problem is at the client-side config.

See [WCF Test Client and WebHttpBinding](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/deabd25b-a219-4e95-9826-d40dc2f75543/).

> This is a limitation of the web
>   programming model itself. Unlike SOAP
>   endpoints (i.e., those with
>   BasicHttpBinding, WSHttpBinding, etc)
>   which have a way to expose metadata
>   about itself (WSDL or Mex) with
>   information about all the operations /
>   parameters in the endpoint, there's
>   currently no standard way to expose
>   metadata for a non-SOAP endpoint - and
>   that's exactly what the
>   webHttpBinding-based endpoints are. In
>   short, the WCF Test Client won't be
>   useful for web-based endpoints. If
>   some standard for representing
>   web-style endpoints emerges when WCF
>   ships its next version, we'll likely
>   update the test client to support it,
>   but for now there's none widely
>   adopted.

Comment: @stimpy77, I simply quoted from the linked answer by a MS employee. In WCF, the binding is called [WebHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx) and in WSDL 2, it's called [HTTP Binding](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20-adjuncts/#http-binding), but it's clear enough from the context what "web-based" means here. The term REST goes way beyond just exposing the methods via HTTP. It's about treating things as resources and using HTTP verbs etc. See [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think your config is wrong,you should add node security mode="None" and attribute bindingConfiguration="NoneSecurity"

Change as my config, try again:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoneSecurity"
          maxBufferPoolSize="12000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="12000000" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="12000000" maxArrayLength="12000000"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Elong.GlobalHotel.Host.IHotelAPIBehavior"
        name="Elong.GlobalHotel.Host.IHotelAPI">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NoneSecurity" contract="Elong.GlobalHotel.Host.IIHotelAPI">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Elong.GlobalHotel.Host.IHotelAPIBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  I had a similar problem, the solution was in a minor error in the message alias ... that very generic message ... in our case was assigned a Boolean false if the right is true.
  This value was in the MDM application that was running on websphere.
```

the path in my case:

```
   /opt/infamdm/hub/server/resources/cmxserver.properties
   /opt/infamdm/hub/cleanse/resources/cmxcleanse.properties
```